# How to get roof access via Anderson Venting Roof Window

Tags: windows, roof

I have an Anderson Venting Roof Window in my attic that I'd like to get through for some roof access.  I believe it is an [RV model, as seen on pg 11 of this Anderson parts catalog](https://www.andersenwindows.com/~/media/aw/files/technical-docs/parts-catalog/partscatalog-windows-1983-2009--400series-ventingroof-stationaryroof.pdf)

I've removed the operator cover, but I can't see a way to disengage the operator arm from the sash.  There is a slot in the center of the sash rail that it appears the arm shoes should fit through, but there is no play in the arms to move to that position.

I even removed the center screw (was in the dark hole at the base of the two arms) but that didn't give any additional play whatsoever.

Below is a picture of the window fully open (approx. 8 inches).  How can I get the window open further?

[image: Anderson Venting Roof Window, fully open]

Comment: can you move one arm to center?

Comment: @jsotola - No, that's just it - it looks like I should be able to, but there is just not enough play.  I've tried with it full open, as shown in the picture, and slightly less open, in case a little space between the arms would help.  I can only get them over maybe a half inch, but not near enough to the gap in the center.

Comment: all i can think of, is that pulling the crank somehow disengages the gears inside the device and allows the arms to swing independently

Comment: Nope - pulling the crank handle off just exposes the grooved axle that turns the gears.  The so-called operator seems to be a single piece that can't be disassembled at all.

Comment: Where the arms connect to the black sliding bracket, Can you pull the arm away  ( *down for the one on the right and up for the left* )  from the bracket thereby pulling the pivot pin out of the black bracket ? What is the function of the springs and does disconnecting them do anything?

Comment: You could just release the spring tension and unscrew the opening mechanism from the wood frame, not  fun for repeated access but once maybe ok.  Have you contacted Anderson Windows ?